# Django db transaction set_autocommit and CONN_MAX_AGE

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions

I want to make an atomic transaction and my database is PostgreSQL.

Here's how I've been making transaction so far:

```
transaction.set_autocommit(False)
try:
    do_stuff()
    transaction.commit()
except:
    transaction.rollback()
    raise
finally:
    transaction.set_autocommit(True)
```

Doc says I could do it like this:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    do_stuff()
```

Are both code the same?

I have a connection pool `CONN_MAX_AGE=60` in my `settings.py`.

What happens with the following scenario:

1. first request sets autocommit to `False`
2. second request makes db updates
3. first request raises and exception, rollbacks, and sets autocommit back to `True`

Will my updates in 2. survive?

Would it be different with `transaction.atomic()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `transaction.atomic()`, since its purpose is to do exactly the thing you want.

You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.1/django/db/transaction.py#L222). The most obvious difference is that Django's version has support for "nested" transactions using savepoints. You can trust that this code is well-tested and widely used.

Regarding your scenario, your updates in step 2 should survive in either case, since autocommit applies at the database connection level, and the two concurrent requests will be using different database connections.

Comment: An important difference is that a successful inner atomic block can still be rollbacked by an outer atomic block (eg. if you have set ATOMIC_REQUESTS to True).